# Validate Kubernetes Object Creation

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I would like to implement functionality (or even better reuse existing libraries/APIs!) that would intercept a kubectl command to create an object and perform some pre-creation validation tasks on it before allowing kubectl command to proceed.

e.g. 
check various values in the yaml against external DB for example
check a label conforms to the internal naming convention
and so on..

Is there an accepted pattern or existing tools etc?
Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is by creating a [ValidatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook). It's not for the faint of heart and even a brief example would be an overkill as a SO answer. A few pointers to start:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook

https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-admission-webhooks/

https://container-solutions.com/a-gentle-intro-to-validation-admission-webhooks-in-kubernetes/

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I usually append - - dry-run to kubectl command to check and validate the YAML config